# arm cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so: undefined symbol: pthread_atfork

Tags: linux, cryptography, synology

I'm trying to install [HomeAssistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) on a Synology ds213j (arm).
It depends on [cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography), which i installed using `pip install cryptography` (v2.9.2). During the home assistang start sequence, an error appears in the log

```
cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so: undefined symbol: pthread_atfork
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I have the similar issue. Did you maybe find a way to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: It seems that the libraries provided with Synology doesn't support pthread_atfork. I found [this post](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=30132&p=119287&hilit=pthread#p120183) with a possible solution, although given my lack of expertise on Linux systems I couldn't make it work. Hope it helps!